# Need help with understanding why $\ell^p$ is reflexive for $1 < p < \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm having difficulties understanding the following proof:

[image]

I'm used to seeing different notation (used in Erwin Kreyszig's functional analysis) where the canonical map is $C: X \to X''$ with $x \mapsto g_x$. And $g_x: X' \to \mathbb{K}$ where $f \mapsto f(x)$

In the image above I'm having trouble making the notation the same as I'm familiar with. And I don't quite follow how $F(y)(x) = \sum x(j)y(j) = G(x)(y).$ Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: He DEFINES  F(x)(y) and G(x)(y) as equal to $\sum x(j)y(j)$. It is easy to show this is finite, but not so obvious that F and G are isometries.

Comment: @user254665 Do you know if there is somewhere I can find a more simpler proof?

Comment: I learned it from Functional Analysis,Vol. 1 by Kolmogorov and Fomin.( A long time ago.) BTW the function f(x) from $l_p$ to $l_q$ where $F(p)(f(p))=\|p\|_p^2=\|f(p)\|_q^2$ although not linear ,is  a homeomorphism from $l_p$ to its dual space